# How to use Postman native client to capture API requests during Protractor test execution

Tags: protractor, postman, e2e-testing, web-api-testing

I've built out an extensive end-to-end test suite for our application using Protractor and I'm now setting my focus on our back end API which doesn't have any documentation or automated tests.

My goal is to capture API calls made during my protractor execution using postman's native Windows client. This will allow me to build out a rough collection of our applications API calls to get started in building documentation and automated tests. However, I have not been able to successfully capture any API request using postman's native client. Normally, I would capture request through the Chrome application, but protractors browser instance does not allow browser extensions to be enabled during execution.

I have searched Google, YouTube, stack overflow and postman's own documentation but I've had no luck with any of the solutions that are suggested. Has anyone been able to get postman's native client to capture requests? If so, how? I've attempted to use the native clients proxy settings, but have had no luck so far.

Comment: Try Browsermob proxy `https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy`

Comment: If they are your own Protractor tests - wouldn’t you already have that request information available to you?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the Postman desktop app, I don't think you can set that up.  As @Barney suggested in the comments, you can try to use [browsermob-proxy](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy).

I attempted something similar in the past but have since abandoned it (our backend team wrote their own tests) so I'm not positive all the code still works, but here's the gist (also cant remember my original source of info, but possibly this since my config looks almost identical: https://github.com/afternoon/protractor-browsermob-test/blob/master/protractor.conf.js)

In your config, you'll require `browsermob-proxy` in your config and set a few parameters.

```
// conf.js
var Proxy = require('browsermob-proxy').Proxy,
    Q = require('q'),
    proxy;

exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    capabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        proxy: {
            proxyType: 'manual',
            httpProxy: 'localhost:8888',
            sslProxy: 'localhost:8888'
        },
    }

    onPrepare: function () {
        var deferred = protractor.promise.defer();
        proxy = new Proxy();
        Q.ninvoke(proxy, 'start', 8888).then(function (data) {
            browser.params.proxy = proxy;
            browser.params.proxyData = data;
            return data;
        }, function (err) {
            deferred.reject(err);
        }).then(function (data) {
            proxy.startHAR(browser.params.proxyData.port, 'test', function (err, resp) {
                console.log('Start HAR');
                deferred.fulfill();
            });
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    },

    onComplete: function () {
        return proxy.getHAR(browser.params.proxyData.port, function (err, harData) {
            if(err) throw err;
            // HERE IS YOUR LIST OF HTTP CALLS
            var data = JSON.parse(harData);
            console.log(data);
        });
    },

    onCleanUp: function () {
        return Q.ninvoke(proxy, 'stop', 8888).then(function (err) {
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log('Stopped server!');
        });
    }
};
```

And then the rest is up to you.  Your HTTP calls will be in the `data` variable that is created in `onComplete`.  This will include ALL http calls, so you'll likely need to filter through some unwanted data.